# Next.js - Is it possible to detect when a page is accessed directly or via <Link> or router.push.?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to implement some conditional scrollTo behavior depending whether the page is accessed directly by typing the URL into browser VS when the page is rendered as a result of a route navigation via `<Link>` or `router.push()`

**Is there a way to distinguish between the two in Next.js?**

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks to some hints in the comments i've found one way but not sure if its any reliable:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(router.components).length == 2) {
      console.log("Is fullpage refresh");
    } else {
      console.log("Is is route change");
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Yes, when you access to a page for the first time via url, router.query is undefined. You can check it.

Comment: Hi @VicenteC I did try checking with an `useEffect(() => {
    console.log(router);
  }, []);`  but query is an empty object for both cases. There is however router.components which looks like its tracking if other pages have been rendered before.

Comment: @CristianE. can you elaborate your comment. How `router.components` tracking the page load

Comment: @fahadshaikh This was ages ago. But I think `router.components` was something similar to browserHistory which held an array of previous paths pushed to it. The array length of this object would tell me if its initial page render or if previously there were other pages displayed. I do not remember why I needed that.